# HTML Form Button

Tags: php, html

I want use my own button in form

When i'm using

```
<form method="post" action="check_login.php">
    <input class="textbox" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Login">
    <input class="textbox" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">

    <div id="buttonPlace">
        <p>Remember Me</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Log in!" />

</form>
```

it works great. I would like to use my own button. When Im using this code :

```
<form method="post" action="check_login.php">
    <input class="textbox" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Login">
    <input class="textbox" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">

    <div id="buttonPlace">
        <p>Remember Me</p>
    <div id="buttonLogin" type="submit">sing up</div>

</form>
```

Button doesn't work.
Why?

Comment: You cannot assign types to a div. You can however submit the form using JQuery when doing a click on the div.

Comment: pls .. try to read and understand basic html - tags <div type="submit" where have you found such thing?

Comment: You could change <Div tpe="submit"> to <button type="submit"> though

Comment: I think you just want to be able to style your button in which I would recommend you here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236018/how-to-style-submit-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<form method="post" action="check_login.php">
  <input class="textbox" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Login">
  <input class="textbox" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
  <div id="buttonPlace">
    <p>Remember Me</p>
    <button id="buttonLogin" type="submit">Sign up</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Div can't have type="submit" property, only form inputs can have different input types property. If you want to style your submit button, use:

```
<input class="submitbutton" type="submit">Sign up</input>
```

and then define css style for your button class:

```
.submitButton {
   .width: 60px;
   .height: 20px;
   .color: #dd5599;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit form on click of your div, use need to assing its click a function to sumbit the form :-

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$( "#buttonLogin" ).click(function() {
 $( this ).closest("form").submit();
});
}
```

However, it is better to use button or input for submission.