# How do you style a type="file" or type="submit" button?

Tags: html, css

I'd tried giving it a class and changing little stuff (like font or background) but it's not responsive.

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/zacharydl/4QezZ/

Comment: Same thing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236018/how-to-style-submit-button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styling of "submit" buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104120/styling-of-submit-buttons)

Comment: Please try searching for your question before asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>

<input type="button" class="button" value=" Button">
```